# mongoDB distict problems

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

It's one of my data as JSON format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfdb412a80939b6ed682090"),
    "accounts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bf106eee639bd0df4bd8e05"),
            "accountType" : "DDA",
            "productName" : "DDA1"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bf106eee639bd0df4bd8df8"),
            "accountType" : "VSA",
            "productName" : "VSA1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bf106eee639bd0df4bd8df9"),
            "accountType" : "VSA",
            "productName" : "VSA2"
        }
    ] 
}
```

I want to make a query to get all productName(no duplicate) of `accountType = VSA`. 
I write a mongo query:

```
db.Collection.distinct("accounts.productName", {"accounts.accountType": "VSA" })
```

**I expect:** `['VSA1', 'VSA2']`

**I get:**  `['DDA','VSA1', 'VSA2']`

Anybody knows why the query doesn't work in distinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second parameter of [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method represents:

> A query that specifies the documents from which to retrieve the distinct values.

But the thing is that you showed only one document with nested array of elements so whole document will be returned for your condition `"accounts.accountType": "VSA"`.

To fix that you have to use Aggregation Framework and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) nested array before you apply the filtering and then you can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-by-null) with [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) to get unique values. Try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$accounts"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "accounts.accountType": "VSA"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            uniqueProductNames: { $addToSet: "$accounts.productName" }
        }
    }
])
```

which prints:

```
{ "_id" : null, "uniqueProductNames" : [ "VSA2", "VSA1" ] }
```